# Changing data in array with substr in loop

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, for-loop, substr

I have a list of words in myArray, I need to make them all have 12 symbols, no more, no less. So first of all I weed out all words shorter than 12 symbols. IT WORKS. But then I must to cut extra symbols in words longer than 12 symbols. I use **array12[j].substr(0,12);** and its not working. 
My question is: How to change data in array "on the fly" - in a loop? Trace I use after substr returns me same array long words, without cut.

```
function myArrayLoopFunction()
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) // this works fine
    {
        if (myArray[i].length >= 12) {
            array12.push(myArray[i]);
        }
    }  
    for (var j:int = 0; j < array12.length; j++)
    {
        if(array12[j].length > 12 )
        {
            array12[j].substr(0,12); //doesnt work
            trace(array12[j]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one loop. I think your mistake is that you're not assigning the result of the substr method back to your array:

```
    function myArrayLoopFunction()
    {
        for (var i:int = 0, str:String; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            str = myArray[i];

            if (str.length >= 12) {
                myArray[i] = str.substr(0, 12);
            }
        }     
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning the substring to anything.

```
array12[j].substr(0,12);
```

should be

```
array12[j] = array12[j].substr(0,12);
```